# Why don't I need to create an object?

Tags: java, swing, object, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.JoptionPane;

class Hat
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
   {

      String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number");
      String sn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second number");

      int num1 = Integer.parseInt(fn);

      int num2 = Integer.parseInt(sn);

      int sum = num1 + num2;

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The answer is " +sum,"the title");
   }
}
```

Why is it not necessary to create an object in order to use showInputDialog method from the JOptionPane class?
Why is null used in showMessageDialog method?

Comment: Because it's `static`.

Comment: Search for static fields and methods in Java.

Comment: Please note that your code is broken because it accesses Swing Components from outside the EDT. Before anything relevant with Swing read up on usage of the Event Handling Thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `showMessageDialog` method is `static` and therefore exists on the class not on an instance. [Here is a little more explanation about static methods](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function/)

The first parameter is the parent which specifise relative to which other Frame the OptionPane belongs. If it is `null`, the OptionPane is independent of any other Frame. [See the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
> parentComponent - determines the Frame in which the dialog is
> displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default
> Frame is used
```

Comment: IMO, you're the only one to understand the question.

Comment: I just got lucky to see that there are actually two questions in this.  Failed to see this in many other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Because `showInputdialog` is a static method. It is not logically attached to an object. It is rather a functionality exposed by the class itself.

Answer (score -1):

All methods/variables used in that method are either method scoped or static. JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() for example is static, while num1/num2 are all method scoped.